# C++ Compilation Error. "Stack does not name a type."

Tags: c++, class, c++11

I am new to C++ and I am trying to understand stacks, and how classes work, but I can't seem to get my program to compile at all. I keep getting stupid errors, and I tried searching around the web, but couldn't find anything helpful. I apologize in advance if this question is very dumb. I am new to C++ and I didn't know anywhere else to turn to.

Thank you.

Whenever I try compiling(make), I get this error:

> stacks.cpp:4:1: error: ‘Stack’ does not name a type stacks.cpp:7:6:
>   error: ‘Stack’ has not been declared stacks.cpp:7:18: error: ‘string’
>   was not declared in this scope stacks.cpp:7:18: note: suggested
>   alternative: /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stringfwd.h:65:33: note:
>   ‘std::string’ stacks.cpp:7:27: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’
>   token make: *** [stacks.o] Error 1

Stack.h

```
#ifndef _STACK
#define _STACK
// template <class ItemType>;
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Stack{
    static const int MAX_STACK = 10;
    private:
        string data[MAX_STACK];
        int top; 
    public:
        Stack();
        bool pop(); 
        bool push(string item);
        string peek();
        bool isEmpty();
};
#endif
```

Stack.cpp

```
  #include <cassert>

    Stack::Stack(){
        top = -1;
    }
    bool Stack::Push(string s){
        bool result = false;
        if(top > MAX_STACK - 1){
        ++top;
        data[top] = s;
        result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }
    bool Stack::Pop(){
        bool result = false;
        if(!isEmpty()){
            --top;
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }
    string Stack::peek() const{
        assert(!isEmpty());
        return data[top];
    }
```

Tester.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "stacks.h"
int main(){
    Stack test; 
    test.push("Hello");
    test.push("Yes!");
    while(!test.isEmpty()){
        cout << test.peek();
        test.pop();
    }
}
```

MakeFile:

```
CXX = g++

CXXFLAGS = -Wall -ansi -std=c++0x

TARGET = execute

OBJS = Tester.o stacks.o

$(TARGET) : $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS)

Tester.o : Tester.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o Tester.o Tester.cpp

stacks.o : stacks.cpp stacks.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o stacks.o stacks.cpp

.PHONY : clean
clean:
    rm $(OBJS)
```

Comment: Is the file `stacks.h` or `stack.h`? Also are you including the header in `stack.cpp`?

Comment: you need to include `stacks.h` in `stacks.cpp`.

Comment: As for good practise: A using namespace directive in global scope is not supposed to appear in a header file since it pollutes the global namespace in every cpp file the header is included in.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to include `Stack.h` in `Stack.cpp` .... also you are including `stacks.h` which is not present include `Stack.h` in `Tester.cpp`...hope this will help..

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `stack.h` in your file `stack.cpp`.

Also:

```
#include "stacks.h"
```

Should be `stack.h` if that is the name of the file.